# Angular 2 User Level and Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created angualar 2 firebase project which has capable of add delete edit post.for authentication im using firebase gmail authentication.things working perfect for this point .but i want to create admin he can see the post.when im enter myexample.com/admin i want to go to admin page in same site that admin page should be email verication.but when  when i type that url(myexample.com/admin) user login page displaye .im newbie to web development.

my routes.ts

```
      const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '',  redirectTo:'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
     { path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
     { path:'admin',component: AdminLoginComponent},
     { path: 'main', component:AdminBodyComponent  },
     { path: 'adminpanel', component:AdminComponent  },
     { path: 'posts',component:PostsComponent},
     { path: 'addposts',component:AddPostComponent},
     { path: 'editposts/:id',component:EditpostComponent}
      ];
```

---

app.component.ts

```
      this.authService.af.auth.subscribe((auth)=>{

      if(auth == null && this.router.url != '/admin'){
          //not logged int

          this.isLoggedIn =false;
          this.displayName='';
          this.userMail=''; 
          this.router.navigate(['login']);

      }else if(this.router.url == 'admin'){


          this.isAdmin=true;
          this.router.navigate(['admin']);

      }
      else{
          //logged in

          this.isLoggedIn=true;
          this.displayName=auth.google.displayName;
          this.userMail=auth.google.email; 
          this.router.navigate([''])
      }
  })

 }
```

Comment: you are looking for Route Guards, detailed example of similar scenario is at [official documentation here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards), Cheers!!

Comment: i read this but i cant understand some concept .can you give me little help that would be great

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, and what are you not understanding.

Comment: simply i want to know how to add two separate login one for normal users others for administrator.

Comment: i updated some code.